# How to measure time a function takes to execute from an erlang shell?

Tags: erlang

Is there is a simple way to measure a function's execution time if I run that function from an erlang shell?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Please see the article [Measuring Function Execution Time](https://erlangcentral.org/wiki/Measuring_Function_Execution_Time).

It is all based on [timer:tc/3](http://www.erlang.org/doc/man/timer.html#tc-3) for the measurement.

Comment: The page is no longer reachable, do you have an updated link?

Comment: Updated, the link points to the same article at erlangcentral now.

Comment: Please include a real answer, not just a link. This link is dead again.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to measure an anonymous function:

```
1> TC = fun(F) -> B = now(), V = F(), A = now(), {timer:now_diff(A,B), V} end.

2> F = fun() -> lists:seq(1,1000) end.
3> TC(F).
{47000,
 [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,
  23,24,25,26,27|...]}
```

average of N runs:

```
4> TCN2 = fun(T,F,0) -> ok; (T,F,N) -> F(), T(T,F,N-1) end.
5> TCN = fun(F,N) -> B=now(), TCN2(TCN2,F,N), A=now(), timer:now_diff(A,B)/N end.

6> TCN(F, 1000).
63.0
```

Answer (score 0):

I am learning `Erlang` and this is one of the exercise in the book, here it how I attempted it

**lib_misc.erl**

```
time_taken_to_execute(F) -> Start = os:timestamp(),
  F(),
  io:format("total time taken ~f seconds~n", [timer:now_diff(os:timestamp(), Start) / 1000]).
```

and on `command-line`, I do

```
1> lib_misc:time_taken_to_execute(fun() -> 1 end).
total time taken 0.003000 seconds
ok
2> lib_misc:time_taken_to_execute(fun() -> [Num || Num <- lists:seq(1, 100)] end).
total time taken 0.085000 seconds
ok
3> lib_misc:time_taken_to_execute(fun() -> [Num || Num <- lists:seq(1, 10000000)] end).
total time taken 9354.205000 seconds
ok
4>
```

Is that something you were looking?

Comment: You worried me there!!
You have to divide by 10^6 to get correct results.